# New page same as home page react

Tags: reactjs

have any some idea why when I try to put new page "Signin" in react I get the "Home" page ? The only content in SignInPage is h1"Sign In" why i get the home page before import it ?

```js
import React from 'react';

const SigninPage = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Sign in</h1>
        </div>
    );
};

export default SigninPage;

import React from 'react'
import './App.css';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route} from 'react-router-dom'
import Home from './pages';
import SigninPage from './pages/signin';

function App() {
  return (
    <Router >
      <Switch>
      <Route path="/" component={Home} exact />
      <Route path="/signin" component={SigninPage} exact />
      </Switch>
     <Home />
   
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 2):

Also your component Home is written without route so its always rendered

```
<Home />
```

Comment: Acctually its still not working when i click Signin i get "http://localhost:3000/signin" but its still homepage maybe im stupid 

Answer (score 1):

The order of the `<Route/>` components matters.  Basically it'll try to match from first to last.  And since `/` matches everything, that'll always win.  So that one should be last.  Always remember to order them from most specific to least specific:

```
<Switch>
  <Route path="/signin" component={SigninPage} exact />
  <Route path="/" component={Home} exact />
</Switch>
```

Comment: Thanks for advice i will remeber about it in future :)